# Where to put files needed by web pages

Tags: html, apache, tomcat

I have some PHP and HTML pages that need to access some files (images files for example) and display them.

Where should I put these files? As I know that it is not recommended (for security reasons) to let the web pages access files in the file system of the server (like in the `home` directory for example).

I need to put the files (the images) in a folder where I have the rights to create new files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put files in virtual directory of your server, for example if you are using XAMPP then put your files in "htdocs" folder. if you are using WAMP then put your files in "www".

Comment: Thank you KPBird, I am using apache, I will create a directory inside www and put my files there then.

Comment: if you are using plain apache http server then you need to configure php over it, I suggest to use XAMPP (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) which is pre configured apache, php, mysql , etc..

Comment: I am actually using apache and tomcat. I now created a folder in /var/ directory and i putted my images there. The folder is read and write accessible fore everyone, but unfortunately the web page is still not able to find the files. Actually I am not using php in this page, I am using ajax JQuery go get the files inside the that folder, but it is not working.

Comment: tomcat only support jsp & servlet, it does not support php files, you can put html files, put your files in webapps directory, you can create your own directory inside webapps

Comment: Sorry KPBird, I have edited my comment, there is some new information in it, thank you.

Comment: when you provide src in img tag that image must be inside virtual directory of server, in case of tomcat it is webapps, web server never allow to access any file out side virtual directory, I suggest you to put image in webapp -> project dir -> image and try to access it

Answer (score 0):

Add a directory inside of your www folder and put your web pages there.
Then you can access the pages as 
    localhost/foldername/page